# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtime'. Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-core:7.0.2

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, groovy

- I am getting this error when issued grails run-app app over grails
  4.0.8. I am in upgrading process from grails 2.2.4 to grails 4.0.8 when i got this error. I checked grails doc for GORM 7.0 but could
  not help. gradle.properties:
- grailsVersion=4.0.8
  gorm.version=7.0.2
  org.gradle.daemon=true
  hibernateCoreVersion=5.1.5.Final
  org.gradle.parallel=true
  org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx1024M`

build.gradle:

-

```
buildscript {
       repositories {
           maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
           classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.0"
           classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4"
           classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.2.4"
           classpath "org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13"
       } }
   
   version "0.1" group "test123"
   
   apply plugin: "eclipse" apply plugin: "idea" apply plugin: "war"
   apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web" apply plugin:
   "com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries" apply plugin:
   "com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline" apply plugin:
   "org.grails.grails-gsp"
   
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
       maven { url "https://repo.opennms.org/maven2" }
       flatDir {
           dirs 'lib'
       } }
   
   configurations {
       developmentOnly
       runtimeClasspath {
           extendsFrom developmentOnly
       } }
   
   
   dependencies {
       developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
       implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
       implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-core"
       implementation group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-datastore-core', version: '7.0.1.RELEASE'
       implementation 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-neo4j:7.0.2.RELEASE'
       implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
       provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-logging"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
       implementation "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
       implementation "org.grails.plugins:cache"
       implementation "org.grails.plugins:async"
       implementation "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
       implementation "org.grails.plugins:events"
       implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.18.Final"
       implementation "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4"
       implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
       implementation "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
       implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
       console "org.grails:grails-console"
       profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
       runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
       runtime "com.h2database:h2"
       runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
       runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
       runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:3.2.4"
       testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
       testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
       testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
       testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
       testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
       testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.14.0"
       testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.14.0"
       testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.14.0"
       testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.14.0"
       testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.14.0"
       compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13"
       compile "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1"
       compile "org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:0.107"
       compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30"
       compile "io.netty:netty-all:4.1.60.Final"
       compile "org.jboss.netty:netty:3.2.10.Final"
       compile "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.15.6"
       compile "org.snmp4j:snmp4j:2.8.6"
       compile "org.ini4j:ini4j:0.5.4"
       compile "net.percederberg.mibble:mibble:2.9.3"
       implementation name: 'protobuf'
   
   
   
   }
   
   bootRun {
       ignoreExitValue true
       jvmArgs(
               '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always',
               '-noverify',
               '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
               '-Xmx1024m')
       sourceResources sourceSets.main
       String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
       systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive) }
   
   tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
       configure(groovyOptions) {
           forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx1024m']
       } }
   
   webdriverBinaries {
       chromedriver '2.45.0'
       geckodriver '0.24.0' }
   
   tasks.withType(Test) {
       systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
       systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
       systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
       systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver') }
   
   assets {
       minifyJs = true
       minifyCss = true }
```

> An error snap shot is given below:

```
`

A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
    Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtime'.
        Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-core:7.0.2.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-core/7.0.2/grails-datastore-core-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-core/7.0.2/grails-datastore-core-7.0.2.jar
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-core/7.0.2/grails-datastore-core-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-core/7.0.2/grails-datastore-core-7.0.2.jar
           - /lib/grails-datastore-core-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/lib/grails-datastore-core.jar
         Required by:
             project : > org.grails:grails-core:4.0.8
             project : > org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:4.0.8
             project : > org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:4.0.8
       > Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-web:7.0.2.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-web/7.0.2/grails-datastore-web-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-web/7.0.2/grails-datastore-web-7.0.2.jar
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-web/7.0.2/grails-datastore-web-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-web/7.0.2/grails-datastore-web-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C://lib/grails-datastore-web-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C://lib/grails-datastore-web.jar
         Required by:
             project : > org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4
       > Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-support:7.0.2.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.jar
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C://lib/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-support.jar
         Required by:
             project : > org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4
       > Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:7.0.2.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm.jar
         Required by:
             project : > org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:4.0.8
             project : > org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:4.0.8
       > Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:7.0.2.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm.jar
         Required by:
             project : > org.grails.plugins:events:4.0.0 > org.grails:grails-events-transform:4.0.0
       > Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:7.0.2.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm.jar
         Required by:
             project : > org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4 > org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:7.0.4.RELEASE
       > Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-validation:7.0.2.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-validation/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-validation-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-validation/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-validation-7.0.2.jar
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-validation/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-validation-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-validation/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-validation-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-validation-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-validation.jar
         Required by:
             project : > org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-web:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:4.0.8
             project : > org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:4.0.8
       > Could not find org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-support:7.0.2.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.jar
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.pom
           - https://repo.opennms.org/maven2/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.2/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-support-7.0.2.jar
           - file:/C:/Users/test123/Documents/codebase/Grails 4.0.8 Updated/sandbox/test/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-support.jar
         Required by:
             project : > org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:4.0.8 > org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:4.0.8
    
    Possible solution:
     - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
`
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your build is looking for versions like `7.0.4` in places when it should look for `7.0.4.RELEASE`.

- https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-support/7.0.4.RELEASE/
- https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-core/7.0.4.RELEASE/

Comment: A good start is go to https://start.grails.org/ and create a new app (or run `grails run-app appname` locally) and use its `build.gradle` and `gradle.properties` as a starting point.  That will be configured with a consistent and compatible set of core dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Scott Brown for making prompt attention. I did change to 7.0.2.RELEASE. But it is now emerging another runtime error. groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.orm.bootstrap.HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer

Comment: You haven't indicated which method is missing and from where it is being called but it is quite likely that you either have a version mismatch in some dependencies, or you have code in your app which was directly interacting with the `HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer` in a way that is incompatible with the current version.  Impossible to say without either seeing the code or seeing which method is being called and from where, but a better guess is a dependency mismatch.  I believe the version number change mentioned above addresses the problem mentioned in the question. Best of luck!

Comment: @ Jeff Scott Brown  Thanks for pointing out. I did that before, still i am facing it. Please refer below url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66690627/no-signature-of-method-grails-orm-bootstrap-hibernatedatastorespringinitializer

Comment: The problem related to that question is a different problem and I provided a solution over there.